# Positive Definite Operators

Tags: matrices, operator-theory

Consider the symmetric linear operator A, for which its eigenvectors form a complete orthogonal set and all its eigenvalues are positive. Show that A is a positive definite operator.

Show that the product of two symmetric and positive definite linear operators is not always a positive definite operator.

For the second one, I considered the matrices
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
2 & 5 
\end{bmatrix}$$  and
$$B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 2 \end{bmatrix},$$
because their product
$$AB=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 3 \\ -3 & 8 \end{bmatrix}$$
,which is not positive defined, because $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 3 \\ -3 & 8 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}=-1<0$$

For the first one, I used the inequality $x^{T}Ax > 0$, where I found that $x^{T} Ax =  \lambda_1 c_1^2 + \lambda_2 c_2^2 + ... + \lambda_n c_n^2 > 0$, if $x = c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + ... + c_nv_n$,
but I'm not sure if this is correct

Comment: Your matrix $A=B$ is not positive.

Comment: The product of commuting positive definite  matrices is a positive definite matrix. You should look for two noncommuting positive definite matrices. You can always assume that one of them say $A$ is diagonal ,  not a multiple of the identity. The other one should be non diagonal in order to spoil commutativity.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Also, please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: What is your question? is it solution-verification or help for a hint?

Comment: I edited and added another Matrices for the second question, I would like you to tell me if there is any mistake in my answer to the first question.